# Early discoveries combining groups and geometry?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, group-theory, geometry

More specifically:
When were the symmetries of polygons/solids first presented as groups in Cayley tables?

Textbooks often use the symmetries of polygons/solids to introduce group theory,
however, I have found little historical material on
the early discoveries relating groups and geometry.

Comment: Have you looked into the work of Klein on group theory, particularly the Erlangen program?

Answer (score 1):

The earliest applications of groups in geometry are dealing with continuous groups
(Lie, Klein 1872). You seem to be talking about discrete groups. Their earliest application in a geometric subject was in crystallography in the 1879-1900. See 
"Crystallographic groups" in Wikipedia.